# FactoryGirl refer to previous created factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm a little stuck here with my factories, I have a friendships factory

```ruby
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :friendship do |f|
    f.association :user
    f.association :friend, :factory => :user

    trait :authorized do
        authorized true
    end

    trait :pending do
        authorized false
    end

  end
end
```

now inside my user factory I have the following

```ruby
factory :valid_user, :parent => :user do |user|
  user.after(:create) { |u| FactoryGirl.create(:usergroup, :user => u) }
  user.after(:create) { |u| FactoryGirl.create(:friendship, :user => u, :authorized => true) }
  user.after(:create) { |u| FactoryGirl.create(:friendship, :friend => u, :authorized => true) }
end
```

my problem is, is there any way that I can refer to the first friendship which is created to create an inverse friendship of the first friendship (user = friend, friend = user? And besides that, why can't I use the traits inside the block? I have to set :authorized = true and can't use just :authorized.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
factory :valid_user, :parent => :user do |user|
  user.after(:create) do |u|
    FactoryGirl.create(:usergroup, :user => u)

    f1 = FactoryGirl.create(:friendship, :user => u, :authorized => true)
    FactoryGirl.create(:friendship, :friend => u, :authorized => true)

    FactoryGirl.create(:friendship, :friend => f1.user, :user => f1.friend)
  end
end
```

For the second part, FactoryGirl takes key value pairs. That's just how it works.

Comment: But I can do FactoryGirl.create(:friendship, :authorized), and this works, if I set one key => value pair, then it has to be always key => value pairs